# Why is exponent so low when used with hat-quantity in a fraction? Is this a bug?

Tags: math-mode, typography

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\hat{R}^2\quad\frac{1}{\hat{R}^2}
\]
\end{document}
```

which give (I highlight with red for better see the lower "2" in the second expression):
[image]

Comment: That's the standard behavior. In denominators, TeX use the “cramped” style, that raises exponents less than in the “normal” style.

Comment: You could use `\displaystyle`  to set the denominator in the normal style.

Comment: @IanThompson `\textstyle`, but yes.

Comment: @IanThompson and David Carlisle: great advice! Thanks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- I'd forgotten about that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just to follow-up on @DavidCarlisle's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/603893/5001): One can undo cramped-textstyle mode in the denominator of a `\dfrac` expression by issuing the directive `\textstyle`. Conversely, one can force cramped displaystyle by loading the `mathtools` package and making use of its `\cramped` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for 'cramped' macro
\begin{document}
\[
R^2 \quad                     % uncramped displaystyle
\cramped{R^2} \quad           % cramped   displaystyle
\frac{1}{R^2 R^2} \quad       % cramped   textstyle
\frac{1}{\textstyle R^2 R^2}  % uncramped textstyle
\]
\end{document}
```

If you look really closely, you'll notice that the exponent isn't set quite as high in uncramped textstyle math mode as it is in uncramped displaystyle math mode.

Comment: I hesitate which answer I will accept. Your answer give a useful workaround, David Carlisle answer give a explanation.

Answer (score 13):

Not really a bug just a perhaps unfortunate combination of features.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\hat{R}^2R^2\quad\frac{1}{\hat{R}^2 R^2}\quad\frac{1}{R^2 R^2}
\]
\end{document}
```

The superscript on the accented base is positioned to match that on an unaccented base, not raised higher.

denominators are set in "cramped mode" to avoid opening up the fraction.

But with the accented R the fraction is opened up in any case.

This behaviour is really set in the tex core layout rules and the font parameters of the font being used, not directly by LaTeX.

Comment: Good explanation. I never heard about "cramped mode" in LaTeX. Neither in Guide to LaTeX, Fourth Edition, nor in the LaTeX Companion, 2th edition (the later in French translation). Perhaps I forgot to read the good section?

Comment: @quark67 - To learn more about cramped math styles, I would start with pp. 140f. of The TeXbook.

Comment: Your answer and the answer from Mico are equally useful. I hesitate which answer I will accept. You give explanation, he give workaround.

Comment: @quark67 general advice is to accept the one you use, so Mico's I guess:-)  (I have no objection to people accepting competing answers, as long as they are not one of egreg's :-)

Comment: I would've accepted this answer, because it answers the question in the title (rather than the implied "how do I work around this")